# ASP.NET performance under load

Tags: asp.net, iis

I am having problems figuring out why my ASP.NET application cannot sustain a large number of concurrent users.  I am running the VS Load Test Tool and I have tons a valuable data, but struggling to sift through it all.  I am using a Step user load pattern which increases the number of virtual users gradually until reaching about 500.  The tests seem to hum along with no problem until some unhandled exception in the app causes it to crash.  Up until the crash, the memory, CPU utilization and all other perf counters I am monitoring stay totally flat.  But once the crash happens, I observe the following:

1. ASP.NET/Requests Current perf counter spikes
2. ASP.NET/Requests Queued perf counter goes up a tiny bit, but stays less than 10
3. .NET CLR LocksAndThreads/Current Queue Length spikes

After this, the load test never recovers.  (NOTE: I'm not asking for help why the app crashes, that is something else that I am working on separately and will fix, but there could always be a new app crash and I don't want my app to be unrecoverable under load). I can also reproduce this behavior if I just restart IIS in the middle of the load test, or if I start a load test on a freshly restarted IIS instance without letting the number of users gradually build up (just hammer it with 500 users from the get-go).

So my question is, why is it that IIS can't handle a large number of users right when it starts?

- .NET Version: 4
- IIS Version: 7.5
- Site Advanced Settings -> Max Bandwidth: 2^32 (~4 billion)
- Site Advanced Settings -> Max Concurrent Connections: 2^32 (~4 billion)
- App Pool Advanced Settings -> Queue Length: 1000
- App Pool Advanced Settings -> Max Worker Processes: 1

Comment: Under what version of IIS and .NET is this app running on?

Comment: The answer most likely is in the "Advance Settings" of the Application Pool if you could share those as well would help

Comment: Added versions #s and advanced settings to question. Is there anything else needed?

Comment: Please include these properties too: Queue Length property of the App Pool and Maximum Worker processes

Comment: I've added the numbers to the question.  Thank you!

Comment: @Dalorzo: Do you have any suggestions given this new information?  I am a at a total loss.

Comment: same here I am a little puzzled I analyzed the information you provided, reviewed some old loading tests I had made and I don't see a clear reason for this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, upon IIS restarting or App pool recycling, the following will happen :

- the assemblies will have to be reloaded
- the pages will get recompiled
- the SQL connections will be closed

You can :

- check the recycling section of your app pool advanced settings to see if a recycling may trigger on memory limit, regular time, ...
- load some assemblies in the GAC
- check that there is no `batch="false"` attribute in the compilation element of your web.config
- raise the min and max pool size in your SQL connection strings (not forgetting session connection strings)
- check that no time consuming process is taking place upon startup (like some NHibernate dynamic mapping)

Comment: Still, does any of that shed light on why the app can never recover?  It seems like after doing those things on start up the app should be able to start serving requests again.

Comment: @skb I guess you may end up in a recycle loop triggered by one of your errors. Or simply reaching a limit causing the pool to recycle again and again. How much time does it take to have your app up and running for a single user ?

Comment: I am assuming that if I run `iisreset` and wait for it to complete and then run a simple test, the length of time the test takes will be about the time you are asking for, right?  The test is so short that I think this will give me an idea for how long it takes to start back up.  I will check on this and get back to you.